# In Spirit Island, do the actions on Power Cards resolve in the provided order only?

Tags: spirit-island

Spirit Island power cards often have more than one action listed on them.

For example, Pyroclastic Bombardment reads:

> 1 Damage to each [Town]/[City]/[Dahan].
> 1 Damage.
> 1 Damage to [Dahan].

On its own, it doesn't matter what order these effects resolve in. However, there are other cards for which this is not the case, and the order of the damage application could make a difference.

Are we supposed to resolve this from top to bottom, i.e. first line, then second, then third, or can we apply the effects of the card in any order?

Similarly, Share Secrets of Survival reads:

> Each time [Dahan] would be Destroyed in target land, Destroy 2 fewer [Dahan]
> ~ OR ~
> Gather up to 2 [Dahan].
>
> If you have 3 [Air]: You may do both.

If one meets the 3 Air criterion, is it up to the player to decide what order the effects are applied in?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but for clarification, in what situation would you want to gather more before destruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rules for Power Cards under the section for Effects.

> Perform effects in order, skipping any that cannot be followed.